# kaazing websocket cross browser support configuration

Tags: html, websocket, kaazing

Does anyone know how to setup kaazing websockets for use with IE and firefox?  My app works great in Safari and Chrome but I can't get it to work with these two browsers.  It just gives me a `WebSocket is not defined` error.

According to their website, I thought all you needed was to add:

```
<head>
<meta name="kaazing:postMessageBridgeURL"
      content="http://www.example.com/bridge/PostMessageBridge.html" >
</head>
```

But I put the file there and still, it is failing.

Answer (score 3):

You only need that  tag you mentioned if you intend to do cross-origin connectivity in IE6 and IE7.

But if you just want basic WebSocket to work in those browsers the thing you need to do is include the WebSocket.js or ByteSocket.js files. In summary, if you intend to use text messages, then put this in your HTML page:

```
<script src="/html5/WebSocket.js"></script>
```

If you intend to use binary messages, then do this instead:

```
<script src="/html5/ByteSocket.js"></script>
```

This is more fully explained in the documentation here for typical usages of WebSocket:

> https://kaazing.com/getting-started/

Regards,
Robin Zimmermann
Kaazing Product Management

Comment: thanks for the response.  I had not idea about including WebSocket.js.  That's the first I have heard about it.  It does work now on firefox for Mac, but not for windows!  IE is also still failing.  In Firefox for windows I get "Image corrupt or truncated: <unknown> _289[key].onerror();" for WebSocket.js (line 2410)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the gateway are you using?
The step you mentioned is only required if you are integrating with another web server (like Apache). Is that what you're doing?